# Need Root for device administration

Tags: android, android-emulator

1) I don't know that do I need to root the device to use the device administration app in android?

2) In every Emulator unlock the `BootLoader`, So can I lock the `BootLoader` for Emulator?

Comment: why you dont use Genymotion? it's default rooted.!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to root your device in order for your app to use device admin APIs.

To use the Device Administration API, the application's manifest must include the following:

```
 1. A subclass of DeviceAdminReceiver that includes the following:
        - The BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN permission.
        - The ability to respond to the ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED intent, expressed in the manifest as an intent filter.
 2. A declaration of security policies used in metadata.
```

[More details](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).